# attempting to convert a linked list to a circular linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I been working on this assignment for a long time. I finally got the tester to print the content in the list and the methods working, but now I need to connect the elements on the list forming a circle and keep them this way when removing or adding elements. My book doesn't cover anything regarding circular linked list and I attempted to apply the concept of a few samples I seen in here for circular linked list without any success.

I would greatly appreciative any help.

Here is what I have:

```
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
A circular linked list.
 */
public class LinkedList
{  
    private Node last;
    // Don't add other instance fields
    /** 
    Constructs an empty linked list.
     */
    public LinkedList()
    {  
        last = null;
    }

    /**
    Returns the first element in the linked list.
    @return the first element in the linked list
     */
    public Object getFirst()
    {  
        //. . .
        if (last == null) 
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return last.data;
    }

    /**
    Removes the first element in the linked list.
    @return the removed element
     */
    public Object removeFirst()
    {  
        //. . .
        if (last == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object element = last.data;
        last = last.next;
        return element;
    }

    /**
    Adds an element to the front of the linked list.
    @param element the element to add
     */
    public void addFirst(Object element)
    {  
        //. . .
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.data = element;
        newNode.next = last;
        last = newNode;
    }

    /**
    Adds an element to the end of the linked list.
    @param element the element to add
     */
    public void add(Object element)
    {  
        //. . .
        if (last == null)
        {
            addFirst(element);
            //position = last;//had to comment out
        }
        else
        {
            Node newNode = new Node();
            newNode.data = element;
            newNode.next = last.next;
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
    }

    /**
    Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
    @return an iterator for iterating through this list
     */
    public ListIterator listIterator()
    {  
        return new LinkedListIterator();
    }

    private class Node
    {  
        public Object data;
        public Node next;
    }

    private class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
    {              
        private Node position; 
        private Node previous; 

        /**
        Constructs an iterator that points to the front
        of the linked list.
         */
        public LinkedListIterator()
        {  
            position = null; 
            previous = null;
        }

        /**
        Moves the iterator past the next element.
        @return the traversed element
         */
        public Object next()
        {  
            //. . .
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            previous = position; //remeber for remove

            if (position == null)
                position = last;
            else
                position = position.next;

            return position.data; //correct line
        }

        /**
        Tests if there is an element after the iterator 
        position.
        @return true if there is an element after the iterator 
        position
         */
        public boolean hasNext()
        {  
            //. . .
            if (position == null)
                return last != null;
            else 
                return position.next !=null;
        }

        /**
        Adds an element before the iterator position
        and moves the iterator past the inserted element.
        @param element the element to add
         */
        public void add(Object element)
        {  
            //. . .
            if (position == null)
            {
                addFirst(element);
                position = last;
            }
        }

        /**
        Removes the last traversed element. This method may
        only be called after a call to the next() method.
         */
        public void remove()
        {  
            //. . .
            if (previous == position)
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            if (position == last)
            {
                removeFirst();
            }
            else
            {
                previous.next = position.next;
            }
            position = previous;
        }

        /**
        Sets the last traversed element to a different 
        value. 
        @param element the element to set
         */
        public void set(Object element)
        {
            if (position == null)
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            position.data = element;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: According to your class name: "LinkedListIterator". Are you trying to do iterator or circular (double) linked list ?

Comment: It is a inner class Iterator

Comment: Try `root.next = // some_node` and `root.prev= tail;` and `tail.next = root;` and `some_node.next = tail;`. I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you to create Circular Linked List

```
class CircularLinkedList
{
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next, prev;

        public Node(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private Node head;
    private int count;

    public Node getHead()
    {
        return head;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return head==null;
    }

    // Add new node after the "head"
    public void add(int data)
    {
        Node n = new Node(data);
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            head = n;
            n.next = head;
            n.prev = head;
        }
        else
        {
            n.next = head.next;
            n.prev = head;
            head.next = n;
            n.next.prev = n;
        }
        count++;
    }

    // Remove the node pointed by "head"
    public void remove()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
            return;

        if(count==1)
            head = null;
        else 
        {
            Node tmp = head;
            tmp.prev.next = tmp.next;
            tmp.next.prev = tmp.prev;
            head = head.next;
            tmp.next = tmp.prev = null;
        }
        count--;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Node tmp = head.next;
        while(tmp!=head)
        {
            System.out.println(tmp.data+" ");
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will give you an idea how circular linked list is created, nodes are added, printed and deleted.
**NOTE:** As it's your assignment so I have not provided you with the exact code. You may use this and understand and tweak it in the way you require. By this you will have nice idea about Circular Linked List

If you have any issues ahead. Ask us. SO always welcome you :)

Comment: Thanks for helping! I don't think I'm suppose to use a counter for this assignment. Should I be calling methods in the iterator inner class from my add method as to places new nodes correctly? I believe the add method should be adding nodes at the end of the list and connect to the first item in the list.

Comment: @grisson: Could you please let me know how the code breaks at your specified line? As in the `if` part, I'm checking whether `head` is initialized. If Yes only then this statement `n.next = head.next` is executed

Comment: @asifsid88: sry I forget how I test it back then, but I think what I mean is n.next = head.next cause the issue. If you add some int element : [5,2,7] in the test class, and use head.next.data to print the element, you will see the order is [5,7,2], the correct order should be 5->2->7->5->2. And since it is circular linked list, when you use while loop in the print, shouldn't it be a infinite loop?

Comment: I agree with your query regarding insertion order of element. For that we can slightly tweak the code. Rather than attaching the new node after the Head (using next in the above code) we can prepend it (i.e., we can use prev). With this tweak the insertion order for [5,7,2,3] would be 5->7->2->3. And for the printing part. Yes it can be an infinite loop but it does not make sense, as we won't be able to know the content. So when element is encountered the second time (keeping track of Head) we terminate the loop. I hope I answer your question? Please let me know in case of any concern